# Can't login via /user page

Tags: users

I have a Drupal 7 site and all seems to be working well except for one problem I have just discovered.

Users can login via the login block on the home page with no problems.  However, if they go to the /user page and attempt to login they are returned to the same /user page without being logged in.  No error message is displayed.

I have tried emptying the sessions table but that didn't work.

I have also noticed that, occasionally, when I go to the /user page I get a message saying that the one time login link is invalid.  On those occasions I was not trying to access a one time link.

Comment: Some where in your code you must have mentioned 
if(arg(0) == 'user'){// for non logged in users

drupal_got('');
}
 Check that this will be causing the problem

Comment: do you have clean urls enabled? if not, I found going to /user/login always failed in that exact way even if it showed the page correctly, and had to use ?q=user/login until clean urls was established.

Comment: @harsh: I didn't put that code in but it could be in one of the contributed modules I'm using.  Thanks, I'll have a look.

Comment: @Geoff: Clean urls is definitely enabled.  However, I did a test and, while logging in doesn't take at /user, it does if I go to /?q=user

Comment: I've just discovered that the problem is only if I go to the page /user.  I see the login page but it doesn't work.

Everything works fine if I go to /user/login.